# Help in proving that $0\ge \sum_{k=3}^{n}\frac{\left(-1\right)^{k}\left(2k-1\right)}{\left(n-k\right)!\left(k+n-1\right)!}\ln\left(k\right)$

Tags: sequences-and-series

I am trying to prove that
$$0\ge\sum_{k=3}^{n}\frac{\left(-1\right)^{k}\left(2k-1\right)}{\left(n-k\right)!\left(k+n-1\right)!}\ln\left(k\right)$$
But I am stuck. I was wondering if you could please give me some hints as to how I could prove this statement. Please note, I am not looking for a complete solution, just some hints.

My attempts:
I tried grouping together the even and odd terms to get rid of the $(-1)^k$ term. My aim was to show that each of these grouped terms was strictly positive. However, they were not so I could not make this work.

I also tried writing ln(k) using Taylor series and as an integral but I could not get it to converge. Your help is appreciated.